# Microsoft SQL Server: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'PSR_Labor'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am brand new to SQL and wrote the below. I do not understand the boolean I should be using.

```
SELECT 
    ComponentName, 
    Billed / 60 AS CustDecLaborHours, 
    Labor / 60 AS ActualLaborHours
FROM 
    ServiceCenter.Stage PSR_Labor
JOIN 
    ServiceCenter.Stage PSR_Cost_Profit_Center ON ServiceCenter.Stage PSR_Labor.CostCenterID = ServiceCenter.Stage PSR_Cost_Profit_Center.CostCenterID
WHERE 
    ProfitCenterFunctionId = '1000'
```

I have tried to research the solutions however I don't know what Boolean should be there.  I am also unsure if the issues is on the FROM or the ON.

```
SELECT 
    ComponentName, 
    Billed / 60 AS CustDecLaborHours, 
    Labor / 60 AS ActualLaborHours
FROM 
    ServiceCenter.Stage PSR_Labor
JOIN 
    ServiceCenter.Stage PSR_Cost_Profit_Center ON ServiceCenter.Stage PSR_Labor.CostCenterID = ServiceCenter.Stage PSR_Cost_Profit_Center.CostCenterID
WHERE 
    ProfitCenterFunctionId = '1000'
```

I expect that the data is imported into PowerBI.

Comment: Your `ON` clause is syntactically invalid. To join multiple columns, use `AND` and multiple conditions. If you're trying to do something with column aliases, don't -- at least not in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this.  When I researched JOIN I understood it to mean that I joined 2 tables together.  How do I use the JOIN to combine 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the issue is that you have spaces in your table names. This is not a great idea but you can get around it using [square brackets] around the name. Using aliases will help make your queries more legible. Additionally you should always specify which table a column belongs to. It prevent ambiguous errors and aids in debugging later. I guessed at the columns but something like this should be pretty close.

```
SELECT cpc.ComponentName
    , l.Billed / 60 AS CustDecLaborHours
    , l.Labor / 60 AS ActualLaborHours
FROM ServiceCenter.[Stage PSR_Labor] l
JOIN ServiceCenter.[Stage PSR_Cost_Profit_Center] cpc
    ON l.CostCenterID = cpc.CostCenterID
WHERE cpc.ProfitCenterFunctionId = '1000'
```

Comment: When I added brackets to the table Stage PSR_Labor I received the error that it is an invalid object name.  *Note* I do not own the SQL Database therefore have no option to remove the spaces in the name.  When I see the Stage PSR_Labor in PowerBI the icon is a table leading me to believe that is the correct table name.

Comment: My answer is pure guesswork because I have no idea what your table names are and you didn't provide any details about them. If you don't know the names of the tables how did you even begin to attempt writing a query?

Comment: I know the table names as I have access to the database (I just don't own it so I can't rename tables).  The table names originally provided (Stage PSR_Labor & Stage PSR_Cost_Profit_Center) are the true names from the database.  What I don't understand is when I use the brackets [ ] I get an error that says it is an invalid object name which doesn't make sense to me as I can actually see the table names and I have imported the table data into PowerBI.  I just want to use SQL to filter down the data imported to speed up the refresh time as I am dealing with 33M rows of data.

Comment: Take a look at sys.tables and find the names as they are in your database. I can't help much there unfortunately other to say you need to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [] for your table name. your table name having space. You must use [].

```
 SELECT ComponentName, Billed / 60 AS CustDecLaborHours, Labor / 60 AS 
 ActualLaborHours
 FROM ServiceCenter.[Stage PSR_Labor]
 JOIN ServiceCenter.[Stage PSR_Cost_Profit_Center]
 ON ServiceCenter.[Stage PSR_Labor].CostCenterID = ServiceCenter.[Stage 
 PSR_Cost_Profit_Center].CostCenterID
 WHERE ProfitCenterFunctionId = '1000'
```

Comment: When I added the brackets I received an error that it is an invalid object name.